# Стоит задача оптимизации кода C#

Tags: c#, winforms, объекты, переменные

Столкнулся с проблемой в Windows Form.
Пример: Создано две кнопки Btn1, Btn2 и textBox1.
[image: Picture1]

Нужно чтобы Btn1 и Btn2 можно было подставлять в одно и тоже место кода в виде переменной, для изменения их свойств.

Пример кода который нужно сделать рабочим

```
namespace TestObject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Метод Для изменения свойств объекта через переменную BtnObj
        private void Btn()
        {
            //Изменение текста
            textBox1.Text = BtnObj.Text;
            //Изменение Локации
            BtnObj.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100);
        }

        private void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Переменной BtnObj передается объект Btn1 и все его свойства
            BtnObj = Btn1;
            //Запуск Метода Btn()
            Btn();
        }

        private void Btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BtnObj = Btn2;
            Btn();
        }
    }
}
```

Какой тип у переменной BtnObj или как можно это реализовать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _Пример кода который нужно сделать рабочим_ - а что в этом коде нерабочее?

Comment: BtnObj не рабочий. Не знаю какой тип переменной нужен чтобы ей предать объект Btn1 или Btn2

Comment: можно навести курсор мыши на Btn1 и Btn2 и посмотреть какой тип покажет студия для них

Answer (score 2):

Тип - `Button`, такой же, как у `Btn1` и `Btn2`.

Answer (score 2):

Видимо, проблема в том, что у вас свойство `BtnObj` нигде не объявлено. Возможно, такой вариант вам поможет:

```
namespace TestObject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public System.Windows.Forms.Button ButtonObj { get; set; }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Метод Для изменения свойств объекта через переменную BtnObj
        private void Btn()
        {
            //Изменение текста
            textBox1.Text = ButtonObj.Text;
            //Изменение Локации
            ButtonObj.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100);
        }

        private void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Переменной BtnObj передаётся объект Btn1 и все его свойства
            ButtonObj = Btn1;
            //Запуск Метода Btn()
            Btn();
        }

        private void Btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonObj = Btn2;
            Btn();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы не создали по видимому BtnObj. А тип у неё Button

```
Button Obj;
Obj = button1;
Obj = button2;
```

Можно поместить и первую и вторую кнопку в Obj, по выбору